# What accuracy and precision can I expect from the iphone magnetometer?

Tags: ios, iphone

What accuracy and precision can I expect from the iphone magnetometer? That is, how close is the reported result to the "true" bearing and what uncertainty is typically reported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The iPhone 4S, 5 and 5C contain good quality components and the compass readings are generally accurate to +/-1 degree – better than can be achieved with a traditional hand-held Brunton or Silva compass. Unfortunately the magnetometer/gyroscope/accelerometer combination in the iPhone 5S is of lower quality and the compass is only accurate to +/-5 degrees.

This is of course assuming that the magnetometer has been calibrated, although the phone will typically prompt you to perform the calibration is the software determines the sensor input to be unreliable.

[Source](http://www.mve.com/filemanager/images/software/FieldMove_clino/DigitalCompassCalibration_FieldMove_Clino.pdf)

Comment: If there is ferrous metal in close proximity, say inside a vehicle, the accuracy is generally very poor. Just moving the device a foot or so can make drastic change.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks. And do you happen to know about the precision that iOS reports?

Comment: @zaph: Can you quantify, even ballpark, the accuracy in those cases? What about indoors if standing in the middle of a room?

Comment: In my car it can be off 10 to 30 degrees. It is the car's fault, I have the same experience with my 50  year old Boy Scout compass. Just walking around my house with a 6 it can be off 10 degrees.

Comment: @zaph: Is that within the accuracy returned by the OS? http://jsfiddle.net/sidonaldson/ZuPYM/

Comment: The data I specified is the chip's accuracy without taking into account any external influences which can cause a discrepancy. The trouble with determining a true accuracy with an uncertainty taking into account these influences is that you cannot be certain of the effect each is having. There's too many variables to take into account. There's no reason why the OS would report anything other than the value supplied to it by the chip, nor why the OS would introduce further inaccuracy.